# How to transfer crease to another object with Data Transfer modifier?

Tags: modeling, animation, subdivision-surface

I have two objects, both with the same level of sub-d.

I want to animate the edge crease by keyframing the mix factor of the Data Transfer modifier but I am unable to even make it work properly in the first place. Note that I made sure to create **two vertex groups with the same name for both objects**, assigned to the edges I want to crease so that the modifier knows which part I am referencing, and I unchecked the object transform toggle in the source.

EDIT : here is the blend file for anyone who might have an idea :
[image]

[image: Crease transfer]

**The Data Transfer works fine with edge sharpness but not with crease as you can see here :**

[image]

Comment: did both objects have the same origin and are positioned on the same place? if yes, pls provide blend file

Comment: You don't need them to have the same origin when you uncheck the Object transform next to the Source selection. It works with weight painting and with edge sharpness but not with crease, which I find it more confusing. I will upload the blend file

Comment: can u pls upload a version of your blend file which is as you present the image here? thx. Because there is no data transfer modifier at all in your blend file

Comment: This might be an edge cases that isn't working properly. Could you please check if Blender's console shows any errors (e.g. complaining about dependency cycles)?